# jQuery siblings, toggleClass affecting other divs

Tags: jquery, toggleclass, siblings

I have an HTML form that begins like this:

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <label for="real_name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control require_name" name="real_name" id="real_name" maxlength="100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 btn-group">
        <div class="btn btn-default btn-private btn-warning">
            <label for="private_check">Private</label>
            <input type="radio" id="private_check" class="privacy_check" name="privacy[real_name_privacy]" value=0 checked="checked" />
        </div>
        <div class="btn btn-default btn-public">
            <label for="public_check">Public</label>
            <input type="radio" id="public_check" class="privacy_check" name="privacy[real_name_privacy]" value=1 />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="row form-group">
        <label for="display_name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Artist Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control require_name" name="display_name" id="display_name" value="This guy" maxlength="100">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 btn-group">
            <div class="btn btn-default btn-private">
                <label for="private_check">Private</label>
                <input type="radio" id="private_check" class="privacy_check" name="privacy[display_name_privacy]" value=0 />
            </div>
            <div class="btn btn-default btn-public btn-warning">
                <label for="public_check">Public</label>
                <input type="radio" id="public_check" class="privacy_check" name="privacy[display_name_privacy]" value=1 checked="checked" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And so on, about a dozen of them. For those .btn divs within the 'btn-group' I've got this jQuery:

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    $(this).find("input").attr('checked', true);
    $(this).siblings().find("input").attr('checked', false);
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-warning btn-default');
    $(this).siblings().toggleClass('btn-default btn-warning');
});
```

Which is supposed to toggle the underlying input on each .btn when the .btn is clicked, and switch its class from .btn-warning to .btn-default, depending on whether or not it's been checked. The above obviously doesn't work: clicking a .btn on the first one will toggle the attribute of its sibling in .btn, but every .btn thereafter will toggle every one above it in the DOM, and the toggleClass doesn't do anything on the .btn group I've clicked on, but clicking a button in the btn-group below it alters the one above as well. I've tried to do it the hard way, with nested divs checking if each button has the necessary classes removed or added depending on the state of its underlying radio button, but got the same result. I think the problem is with siblings(), but anyone have ideas as to how to make this work without traversing the entire DOM looking for every .btn?

Comment: I don't understand what the goal is. What's the functionality you're looking for?

Comment: The problem maybe you use `toggleClass`, by the way, change `attr` to `prop`

Comment: User clicks the .btn, which checks the underlying radio input, and adds .btn-warning to that .btn. .btn-default is for uncheck, .btn-warning is for checked.

Comment: @5-T: using prop doesn't change the attribute when I use it there.

Comment: Why target the btn div instead of the child label element?

Comment: Why would I target the label? The .btn is what I want to change, and what the user is clicking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".btn").click(function (e) {
        if (!$(this).find("input").is(':checked') || !$(this).is('.btn-warning')) {
            $(this).find("input").prop('checked', true);
            $(this).siblings().addBack().toggleClass('btn-default btn-warning');
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EFpVm/)

**Update:**

The second issue is related to duplicate ID's of the radio buttons, you have multiple elements with the id `private_check` and `publi_check` and the corresponding `label` have the `for` attribute set that is the cause of the problem change the ids to `private_check<n>` and `public_check<n>` so that there will be only one element with a specific ID.

```
<label for="private_check1">Private</label>
<input type="radio" id="private_check1" class="privacy_check" name="privacy[real_name_privacy]" value=0 checked="checked" />
```

Comment: That still has the same problem as I already have: changing button states on the second group of buttons changes the top one as well, which is not what I want. Also, it always changes the first set of buttons; if I select on on the third set of buttons on that page, it changes that set and the very first set, but not the second.

Comment: I think you're on the money with that (re: update). I've edited the first few and can at least get the input toggle to work without affecting other divs. But that seems to be the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this you want?

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
   $(this).find("input").prop('checked', true);
   $(this).siblings().find("input").prop('checked', false);
   $(this).addClass('btn-warning btn-default');
   $(this).siblings().removeClass('btn-default btn-warning');
});
```

Comment: Nope. Still changes the first set of buttons when I click on the second, or third, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but still doing the same thing, which is why I think siblings is the problem.